# mysqli.dll not loaded, although present in PHP folder

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, windows-7-x64

I run a php script on Apache 2.4 on Windows 7 which loads library `mysqli`.
The function `extension_loaded('mysqli')` returns `false`.

My `php.ini` includes lines:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and in `{$PHProot}/ext` directory there is indeed aforementioned file. The file `mysqli.dll` is in MySQL Server Folder and I copied it also to php root directory and into `{$PHProot}/ext`.

**EDITS:**

According to `phpinfo()`, correct (above referenced) `php.ini` is used, but no modules were loaded

Any suggestions, what my cause this?

Thanks,
Zbynek

Comment: First thing to do is to check if it appears on your phpinfo (probably not). Then check which php.ini file is used by apache (written in the phpinfo). I don't know on Windows but on Linux there is more than one php.ini file.

Comment: according to A.D., you have to be sure that you have updated the right php.ini file, also, and after each update on php.ini, you have to restart your Apache//IIS//.... server

Comment: I know, values in the post above are taken from actually loaded ini file after restart of the server. No additional ini files are loaded either

Comment: does apache have access to the ext folder? does it loads other extensions?

Comment: Thanks. the folder was not accessible to Apache, hence the problem. That solved it, thank you very much